# How to install Dc++ on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, 18.10

I have recently installed Lubuntu 18.10 (dual-boot with Windows 10) and I am unable to install Linuxdcpp on it. I have tried installing it using `sudo apt-get install linuxdcpp` command but it shows "Unable to locate package".
Please help me install it.

Comment: Most likely `universe` repository is not enabled.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `universe` repository.

Run

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linuxdcpp
```

Ubuntu `cosmic` repositories don't contain `linuxdcpp` for some reason. You can try to search for a PPA if one exists.

Comment: shows " 'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources."

Comment: What is the Lubuntu version?

Comment: ubuntu 18.10 cosmic

Comment: There is no package for cosmic in Ubuntu repos. The latest is seen in bionic.

Answer (score 0):

As of now linuxdcpp isn't imported in Cosmic's Universe repository. However you can install it by following ways.

- You can download the .deb package from [pkgs.org](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/linuxdcpp_1.1.0-4_amd64.deb.html) or [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/linuxdcpp/download) and install it using:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i linuxdcpp_1.1.0-4_amd64.deb
  ```

  And finally install dependencies:

  ```
  sudo apt install -f
  ```
- Or open sources.list with sudo privileges (`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`) and add this line:

  ```
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
  ```

  Update and install linuxdcpp:

  ```
  sudo apt update && sudo apt install linuxdcpp
  ```

Comment: Still showing this in terminal while installing it:
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxdcpp-team/ppa/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

Comment: @PriyaranjanMudliar It looks like you have added some 3rd party repository. Remove that using `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:linuxdcpp-team/release`